# How to send data back from popover page without closing it in ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

How to send data back from popover page without closing it in     ionic2.Below is the data that I want to send back and use it in

```
*ngFor
```

to display data dynamically and this data changes with respect to use selection.

```
PopOverPage.ts
```

```
getFilteredItems(data){
   this.DH.getFilteredItems(data).then(data=>{
   this.DH.myorders=data
})}
```

```
home.ts
```

```
presentPopover(myevent,data) {
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopOverPage,{Data:data});
    popover.present({
       ev: myevent
});}}
```

This there any way to implement it

Comment: why not try to set in a provider class?

Comment: i got it from other post http://stackoverflow.com/a/42178931/7626416